# open an asp website in visual webdeveloper express

Tags: c#, asp.net

Normally, I would be busy with php..but now I have to change something in an asp.net website.

I try to open a website in visual webdeveloper to change the layout. The error states that it is a precompiled website and should open the original file. What does this mean for me.

I can only see a web.config compiled and a PrecompiledApp.config.
Does this mean that I can never open the website to make changes?

Does the express version also compile?

Thanks, Richard

**UPDATE:**

When I asked for the source I was given the following:

1) sitemaster, aspx, aspx.cs, asax, web.config and folders for the images,styles,scripts

2) sln file and a gpState file

How should I load them into the visual webdeveloper express so I can begin exploring what I need to change. The css is easy I guess. Does it run a browser preview, so you can see your changes?

Comment: You tagged your question as asp.net, but you included a reference to asp in your question.  I assume this was a typo and changed it to asp.net for you.  You should be aware that asp and asp.net are not the same thing.

Comment: For your reference, there are two types of ASP.NET projects, one is a "Web site" and the other is a "Web application".  Web applications have all of their code files compiled into a single DLL, whereas web sites retain their individual code-behind files while in production.  Since you are working with a web application, if you can't find the source you'll be in the same situation as if you needed to change any other DLL that you don't have the source for.

Comment: I have updated my answer in accordance with your own update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the source code for this web applicaiton.  Typically there will be an visual studio project or solution file that you open which will include all files you need in your solution explorer.

Once you have this you can look at the source code and modify as needed.  If you have only done PHP before, you will need to do more than open a file and start poking around to get started.  I would recommend finding a good ASP.NET programming tutorial.

NOTE:

You don't *need* to have visual studio or a solution/project file but if you do it will make your life easier.  In a worst case scenario you can look for the code behind files which will be named something like `myPage.aspx.cs`.  Once you change this you will need to figure out how to compile the binaries.

**UPDATE:**

Since you have a solution file (has extension of .sln) and Visual Studio installed you should just be able to double click the solution file.

Comment: I added your answer as an update to your question.  When you have these types of updates please include them in the original question and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's a precompiled site, that is, the source code of each of the pages has been compiled and deployed to the server much in the same way as you'd create a .dll file.

*Somewhere*, someone will have the original source - the .aspx, .aspx.cs files etc.

Non-precompiled sites (dynamically compiled) have all the component files on the server and are compiled at the time of the first request to the server.

If you can't get in touch with the original developer to grab the source files, you may have some luck with [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx). This will allow you to inspect the .dll files to take a stab at recreating the source.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The Express version of Visual Studio will indeed compile web applications for you, but it can't decompile and restore an application to its original source state. With the precompiled application what you have is the end-product, what is to be deployed. In order to make significant changes (if partially compiled) you will need to solution source. If it is fully precompiled then you really can't change a thing.

**Pertaining to your update:**

If no solution (*.sln) and / or project (*.csproj) file is present then the chances are this is a standard file-system type web site where, once loaded, only cares about anything (and everything) under its own root directory (as opposed to a web application that does have these files, where file and folder paths and more are persisted.)

To open this, try these steps:

- Launch Visual Studio
- Click the 'File' menu
- Hover over 'Open' and select 'Web Site'
- Locate the root directory of the web site files
- Click 'Open'

Comment: He says he has a .sln file.  Can't he just double click that to open it?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Yes. Apologies for not being explicitly clear about that - I didn't see it immediately, then didn't think to spell it out after describing the differences between two project types.

Comment: I doubleclicked the sln and the error said it was expecting the files to be in a folder named....etc I changed it accordingly and now I have everything open. Where is the file hiarchie stored so I can adapt it if I want the folders to be present on my desktop or change the name of the folders?